# datepicker How to show more years?

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker and when I open the dropdown to change the year, it shows only 20 years...  The current year.. 10 years before and 10 after.

How can I change it and make it show 40 years.. ? the current year ,20 before and 10 after?

Is that posible?

This is what I have setted

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
 });
 $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "clip");
```

This is the format I have

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-20:+10" // 20 years before and 10 years after the current year
});
$(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "clip");
```

you can use the `yearRange`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the *startDate* and *endDate* properties with this kind of syntax

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     startDate: '-20y',
     endDate: '+20y',
 });
```

Comment: IT does not work, still show me 10 before and 10 after.. Thanks

Comment: This fiddle works https://jsfiddle.net/aq5v1xgt/ But it seems that you are using an old version of bootstrap datepicker. What version is it?